# Javascript variables email link - "To" field is blank

Tags: javascript

How can I do this:

```
var newContactEmail = "abc@cc.com";
document.getElementById('contactEmail').innerHTML = '<a   href="mailto:"' + newContactEmail + '">' + newContactEmail + '</a>';
```

When I click on the mail link, it opens but the "To" field is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `href="mailto:"' + newContactEmail + '" '` try `href="mailto:' + newContactEmail + '" '`.. Else it would look like href = "mailto:"someemail@a.com .

Answer (score 8):

You are putting the closing double quotation mark too soon.

```
var newContactEmail = "abc@cc.com";
document.getElementById('contactEmail').innerHTML = '<a href="mailto:' + newContactEmail + '">' + newContactEmail + '</a>';
```

Comment: cool, nice thank you ... I always get confused with "single" and "double" quotes when dealing with javascripts.

Comment: @jeewan, it happens to the best of us sometimes.

Comment: @jeewan, I'm guessing that was intentional?